# Jquery mobile & Phonegap the first step

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

How do I setup Jquery Mobile and Phonegap? $(document).ready don't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Jquery Mobile with Phonegap exist difficult of startup the basic javascript. Below you can see how to set a simple with hello world.

code: http://jsfiddle.net/zwTQ4/

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">    
    <p>Hello world</p>        
</div><!-- /content -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#indexPage").bind(
         'pageinit',function() {
               alert("Hello world");
             });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I sugges to read the documentation of [jquerymobile, the section about events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html).

One of the first notices there is:

```
Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()
```

Comment: Yes but exist a problem of semantic and make it work is hard for the beginner user.
I pass through this page and have some problems. Other people can be problems too.